# Animation speed inherited from first View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I am experimenting as I am learning Xcode and I have created an app with a menu view controller which then links to 3 maps that are individual view controllers.

All 3 worked perfectly as I wanted, all doing different animations on touch so all was good.

I wanted to add a pop up menu and I followed this guide http://www.samsurge.com/developer/apple/pop-up-menu.php to add it to my mapOne view controller to trial it.

To be fair the guide worked and it did exactly what I wanted it to. The issue that has arisen as a result of using this code is that now the animation on mapTwo view controller now animated using the speed of 0.3 that was used to animate in and out the pop in menu.

This only occurs if I actually use the pop in menu on mapOne view controller.

So if i go to mapTwo view controller first it works as it should.

If I go to mapOne view controller first and do not use the pop in menu and go back to mapTwo view controller the animation there works as it should.

But if I go to mapOne view controller first and click on the pop in menu then go back to mapTwo view controller everything animates at the 0.3 seconds, the speed that the pop in menu animates at on mapOne view controller.

Anyone know what could be casing this?

Here is the code now for my mapOne view controller which includes the code for the pop in menu:

```
#import "GWSMapOneViewController.h"

@interface GWSMapOneViewController ()

@end

@implementation GWSMapOneViewController

@synthesize pandaBigButton;
@synthesize pandaSmallButton;
@synthesize scrollView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // Pop Up Menu

    draw1 = 0;
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 568, 320, 0);
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 0)];
    openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(124, 496, 72, 72);

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)pandaBigButton_clicked:(id)sender
{

    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"Super_Mario_Bros_Jump", CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL);

    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);

    // Big Panda Animation

    pandaBigButton.imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"panda-png-happy"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"panda-png-chewing"],nil];

    pandaBigButton.imageView.animationDuration = 1.0;
    pandaBigButton.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    [pandaBigButton.imageView startAnimating];
}

- (IBAction)pandaSmallButton_clicked:(id)sender
{
    SystemSoundID soundID;
    NSString *soundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Super_Mario_Bros_Mushroom" ofType:@"mp3"];

    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef) [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile], & soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);

    pandaSmallButton.imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"panda-png-chewing"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"panda-png-happy"],nil];

    pandaSmallButton.imageView.animationDuration = 0.2;
    pandaSmallButton.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 6;
    [pandaSmallButton.imageView startAnimating];
}

- (IBAction)OpenMenu:(id)sender {
    if (draw1 == 0) {
        draw1 = 1;
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

        [UIButton beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIButton setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        [UIButton setAnimationDelay:0.0];
        [UIButton setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

        scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 468, 320, 100);
        openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(124, 396, 72, 72);

        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:scrollView];

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    } else {
        draw1 = 0;
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

        [UIButton beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIButton setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        [UIButton setAnimationDelay:0.0];
        [UIButton setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

        scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 568, 320, 0);
        openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(124, 498, 72, 72);

        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:scrollView];

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}



@end
```

The mapTwo View controller that gets overwritten is here:

```
#import "GWSMapTwoViewController.h"

@interface GWSMapTwoViewController ()

@end

@implementation GWSMapTwoViewController
@synthesize cloudAnimate;
@synthesize cloudAnimate1;
@synthesize marioRunning;
@synthesize bowserJump;
@synthesize sun;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Move UIView

    cloudAnimate.center = CGPointMake(400.0, 90.0);
    cloudAnimate1.center = CGPointMake(400.0, 150.0);
    marioRunning.center = CGPointMake(160.0, 456.0);
    sun.center = CGPointMake(-75.0, 235.0);
}


- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    [UIView animateWithDuration:10.0
                          delay:1.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                     animations:^{
                         cloudAnimate.center = CGPointMake(-100.0, 90.0);
                     }
                     completion:NULL];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:8.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^{
                     cloudAnimate1.center = CGPointMake(-100.0, 150.0);
                 }
                 completion:NULL];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:30.5
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         sun.center = CGPointMake(395.0, 100.0);
                     }
                     completion:NULL];

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}


- (IBAction)marioRunning_clicked:(id)sender
{

    if(marioRunning.selected)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.50 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
            marioRunning.center = CGPointMake(160.0, -100.0);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            if (finished) {
                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.00 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
                    marioRunning.center = CGPointMake(-30.5, 456.0);
                } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    if (finished) {
                        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.50 delay:2.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
                            marioRunning.center = CGPointMake(160.0, 456.0);
                        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                            if(finished)  // NSLog ( @"Finished !!!!!" );
                                marioRunning.center = CGPointMake(160.0, 456.0);
                        }];
                    }
                }];
            }
        }];

        // Mario Jump Sound

        SystemSoundID soundID;
        NSString *soundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Super_Mario_Bros_Jump" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef) [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile], & soundID);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);

        // Mario Running Animation

        marioRunning.imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mario-running2"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"mario-running3"],nil];

        marioRunning.imageView.animationDuration = 0.2;
        marioRunning.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 20;

        [marioRunning.imageView startAnimating];
    }

    else

    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.50 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
            marioRunning.center = CGPointMake(350.5, 456.0);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            if (finished) {
                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.00 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
                    marioRunning.center = CGPointMake(-30.5, 456.0);
                } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    if (finished) {
                        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.50 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
                            marioRunning.center = CGPointMake(160.0, 456.0);
                        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                            if(finished)  // NSLog ( @"Finished !!!!!" );
                                marioRunning.center = CGPointMake(160.0, 456.0);
                        }];
                    }
                }];
            }
        }];

        marioRunning.imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mario-running2"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"mario-running3"],nil];

        marioRunning.imageView.animationDuration = 0.15;
        marioRunning.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 19;

        [marioRunning.imageView startAnimating];
    }

    marioRunning.selected = !marioRunning.selected;

}

- (IBAction)bowserJump_clicked:(id)sender
{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
        bowserJump.center = CGPointMake(250.0f, 100.0);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if(finished) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
                bowserJump.center = CGPointMake(250.0, 436.5);
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                if(finished)  // NSLog ( @"Finished !!!!!" );
                    bowserJump.center = CGPointMake(250.0, 436.5);
            }];
        }
    }];

    SystemSoundID soundID;
    NSString *soundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"smb_bowserfalls" ofType:@"wav"];

    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef) [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile], & soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);

}




-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event {

    CGPoint point = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];

    if([self.cloudAnimate.layer.presentationLayer hitTest:point]) {

        SystemSoundID soundID;
        NSString *soundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Super_Mario_Bros_Mushroom" ofType:@"mp3"];

        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef) [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile], & soundID);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);

        cloudAnimate.imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"panda-png-chewing"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"panda-png-happy"],nil];

        cloudAnimate.imageView.animationDuration = 0.2;
        cloudAnimate.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 6;
        [cloudAnimate.imageView startAnimating];
    }
    else if([self.cloudAnimate1.layer.presentationLayer hitTest:point]) {

        SystemSoundID soundID;
        NSString *soundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Super_Mario_Bros_Mushroom" ofType:@"mp3"];

        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef) [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile], & soundID);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);

        cloudAnimate1.imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"panda-png-chewing"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"panda-png-happy"],nil];

        cloudAnimate1.imageView.animationDuration = 0.2;
        cloudAnimate1.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 6;
        [cloudAnimate1.imageView startAnimating];
    }

}

@end
```

Thanks in advance if anyone can help.

Comment: Do you really have 4 different storyboards (4 different files with a .storyboard extension), or are you talking about different scenes (controllers) in a single storyboard? Also, what animation on map2 are you laking about that has the wrong animation time?

Comment: Yea sorry, 1 storyboard and 4 view controllers - my bad. will edit now and add animation for second view controller.

Comment: I can't see why this would happen. The one thing I would change, whether this fixes the problem or not, is to do the openMenu animation using the block based methods like you did for all the other animations.

Comment: Just for clarification, your saying that if you call OpenMenu (should me 'openMenu') on mapOne, the go to mapTwo, every animation in there animates at a speed of 0.3?

Comment: @random - Yes this is exactly what I am saying. If I go to map Two first after launch the animations run at the speed set in mapTwo.m if I go to mapOne then open openMenu and go back to mapTwo all of the animations are running at 0.3 seconds! Grrrr

Answer (score 0):

@rdelmar, credit for this should go to you as I have just tried what you said and it worked.

I changed the structure of the animation to match what I already had used for other animations  and it did the job so thank you so much.

I used this for the mapOne file and everything works as it should now.

```
- (IBAction)openMenu_clicked:(id)sender {
    if (draw1 == 0) {
        draw1 = 1;           
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
            scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 468, 320, 100);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        }];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
            openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(124, 396, 72, 72);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {   
        }];

    } else {
        draw1 = 0;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
            scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 568, 320, 0);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
            openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(124, 498, 72, 72);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];
    }
}
```